# Computationally efficient Gaussian MAP estimation algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, matlab

I have a MAP estimation model for a Gaussian prior and i.i.d Gaussian noise:

$$y=x+n$$

where $x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ and $n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I)$. The MAP estimate is given by

$$ \hat{x} = \arg\max P(X|Y) = (I+\sigma^2\Sigma^{-1})^{-1} y $$

Everything works fine, but the direct application of this, including two matrix inversions, is not computationally efficient. Is there any general purpose algorithm to make this work faster?

Thanks.

Comment: You could look to approximate the outer inversion using a Taylor expansion and truncate at a suitable point.

Comment: Having said that, I don't think you should be doing a second inversion to solve a problem of the form $x = A^{-1}y$ as it is an inefficient way to do it.

Comment: @rwolst , thank you, I am indeed using MATLAB's LS solution (the backslash operator) instead of the last inversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this method doesn't do anything clever in terms of the structure or algorithm, it is quicker in Matlab to do the following:

Notice that
\begin{equation}
\hat{x}=\Sigma(\Sigma+\sigma^2)^{-1}y
\end{equation}

or even better (after seeing Alexey's answer)
\begin{equation}
\hat{x}=y - \left (I+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\Sigma \right )^{-1}y
\end{equation}

We can compare these in Matlab to the initial naive implementation using the code

```
n = 2000;

A = rand(n);
y = rand(n,1);

% Naive
tic
inv(eye(n) + inv(A))*y;
toc

% Mine
tic
B = A+eye(n);
A*(B\y);
toc

% Alexey
tic
B = A+eye(n);
y - B\y;
toc
```

I get answers of

```
Elapsed time is 1.126651 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.246517 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.202166 seconds.
```

In order to get any more really significant speedup, I'm guessing you would have to start taking advantage of the structure of your matrices if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first thing you should try is to use [Woodbury matrix identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).
Using it you get from your initial formula:
$$
(I + \sigma^2 \Sigma^{-1})^{-1} = I - I \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \Sigma + I \right)^{-1} I = I - \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \Sigma + I \right)^{-1}.
$$

Using this formula you require only one matrix inversion instead of two. Another benefit is that you have a nonnegative matrix, and as you add an identity matrix to it, you get a matrix to inverse with mininal eigenvalue at least 1.

Another thing to try is to explore structure of your $\Sigma$ matrix.